# Some files on samba share not showing up on FreeBSD client

Tags: freebsd, samba

I'm running the samba server 4.1.17 on Raspbian. My configuration is:

```
[global]
interfaces = eth0
bind interfaces only = yes
display charset = utf-8
[stfourk]
path=/media/stfourk
valid users = raspi
read only = no
```

This is a problem with the FreeBSD samba client, or more precisely the package `mountsmb2-0.90.2`.

In directories with many files (a few hundreds) only a fraction of files show up (20% or so) if I mount the share with `mount_smbfs`.

Curiously, I *still* get a warning when using `mv -i` even in the case the file on the share, that would be overwritten, is **not** seen by the client.

In Windows 7, the same samba share shows up completely with no files missing.

Comment: Could you include some of the names of the files that do not show up please?

Comment: @Kusalananda: well, hundreds of files don't show up. I don't see anything special about the file names, they seem to be very ordinary like `commath.pdf` for example, a file that simply does not show up on the client.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I solved it, it seems to be a bug of the Linux samba server of which Windows was immune against. Why, I don't know. Updating the samba server to 4.2.14 makes the problem disappear. All files are shown. Thanks for trying to help me.